# Multiple Search Keywords Against A List Of Lists

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, search, mvvm

It's been a couple of days now trying to figure out what's the most efficient way to search a list of lists with thousands of items with multiple keywords in no specific order. I have implemented simple search on other screens but this one is a little tricky. Let me explain.

so lets say my lists look like the below

1. Martial Art

   - Game Of Death
   - IP Man
   - The Protector
2. Comedy

   - Ride Along
   - Police Academy
   - Anchorman
   - Anger Management
3. Action

   - Blood And Bone
   - The Matrix
   - Captain America
   - The Terminator

and if I type in the search box the keyword "man", I expect to see 3 hits, which is easy to accomplish. However if I type in partial keywords such as "a ma" or "ma a" I expect to see Anger Management only. If there's more than one hit, then I should be able to narrow it down by typing more words or simply completing my keywords I have in the search box.

Right now I have some implementation but I'm not too happy with it due to the number of iterations I'm doing. I'm afraid that when we have more data, this search wont perform efficiently and will be slow.

```
public List<ValidAndCompletedModel> Filter(List<string> searchTerms)
{
    var validAndCompleted = new List<ValidAndCompletedModel>();

    foreach (var searchTerm in searchTerms)
    {
        var containingList = ValidAndCompleted.Where(d => ListsContainsSimilarEntry(searchTerm, d.EnglishTranslationTerms)).ToList();
        containingList = containingList.Distinct().ToList();
        validAndCompleted.AddRange(containingList.Where(d => ListsStartsWithSimilarEntry(searchTerm, d.EnglishTranslationTerms)).ToList());
    }
    validAndCompleted = validAndCompleted.Distinct().ToList();


    return validAndCompleted;
}

private bool ListsStartsWithSimilarEntry(string searchTerm, IEnumerable<string> searchList)
        {
            var available = searchList.Any(sl => sl.StartsWith(searchTerm));
            return available;
        }
private bool ListsContainsSimilarEntry(string searchTerm, IEnumerable<string> searchList)
            {
                var available = searchList.Any(sl => sl.Contains(searchTerm));
                return available;
            }
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that performance will be an issue unless your lists have millions of items in them. You should always measure actual usage performance before trying to optimize.

In any case your code simplifies down to this:

```
public List<ValidAndCompletedModel> Filter(List<string> searchTerms)
{
    return (
        from searchTerm in searchTerms
        from d in ValidAndCompleted
        where d.EnglishTranslationTerms.Any(sl => sl.Contains(searchTerm))
        where d.EnglishTranslationTerms.Any(sl => sl.StartsWith(searchTerm))
        select d)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
}
```

That doesn't seem to be too bad. The only thing that stands out is that you're only returning items that both "contain" and "start with" the translation terms, but this means you are only returning items that "start with" and ignoring any that "contain". That might need a rethink.

Now you could go further and simplify your code to this:

```
public List<ValidAndCompletedModel> Filter(List<string> searchTerms)
{
    return (
        from searchTerm in searchTerms
        from d in ValidAndCompleted
        from sl in d.EnglishTranslationTerms
        where sl.StartsWith(searchTerm)
        select d)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
}
```

Alternatively you could avoid the `.Distinct()` call entirely (assuming no duplicates in the `ValidAndCompleted` list) by doing this:

```
public List<ValidAndCompletedModel> Filter2(List<string> searchTerms)
{
    return ValidAndCompleted
        .Where(d => (
            from searchTerm in searchTerms
            from sl in d.EnglishTranslationTerms
            where sl.StartsWith(searchTerm)
            select d).Any())
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: For completeness, don't forget to do case insensitive search. It looks like that's what OP has requested.

Comment: @DavidG - I just directly translated the code. But it would be easy for the OP to drop `.ToLowerInvariant()` in as needed.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned this but the search terms and the string I'm searching against are all in lower case because I've taken care of that somewhere else in my model & VM

Answer (score 0):

Using your films & categories example. Lets say we have a class like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<string> Films {get; set;}
}
```

And our setup of films is this:

```
var filmCategories = new List<Category>
{
new Category { Name = "Martial Arts", Films = new List<string>
        { "Game Of Death", "IP Man", "The Protector" }},            
    new Category { Name = "Comedy", Films = new List<string>
        { "Ride Along", "Police Academy", "Anchorman", "Anger Management" }},           
    new Category { Name = "Action", Films = new List<string>
        { "Blood And Bone", "The Matrix", "Captain America", "The Terminator" }}
};
```

Our search terms are like this:

```
var searchTerm = "g d";
var searchTerms = searchTerm.ToLower().Split(' ');
```

The you can get your search results in 1 shot like this:

```
var results = filmCategories
    .SelectMany(category => category.Films)
    .Where(film => 
        searchTerms.All(term =>
            film.ToLower().Split(' ')
            .Any(word =>            
                word.StartsWith(term))));
```